# Determine relationship between commits

Tags: git, bash

In a linear history, two commits A and B can have one of three states:

- A and B are the same commit
- A strictly before B
- B strictly before A

Git's nonlinear history allows for four additional options

- A and B share both a parent and child
- A and B share a parent but not a child
- A and B share a child but not a parent
- A and B share nothing

I'm not sure how to achieve the last two without using graft points, but it *could* happen.

What I'm unsure of how to accomplish is a determination of this relationship in a simple manner--at the moment I can only think of a somewhat odd `rev-list` and solution where one tests each case individually:

```
[[ "$a" = "$b" ]] && echo "same"
git rev-list "$b" | grep -q "$a" && echo "a before b"
git rev-list "$a" | grep -q "$b" && echo "b before a"
cat <(git rev-list "$a") <(git rev-list "$b") | sort | uniq -cd | grep -q 2 && echo "A and B share parents"
cat <(git rev-list --children "$a") <(git rev-list --children "$b") | sort | uniq -cd | grep -q 2 && echo "A and B share children"
```

There has to be a better, gittier way of doing this, so what is it?

Comment: `git log --graph` or `gitk --all` to view it visually?

Comment: For visual examination that's fine; this is for more like "a bug was fixed in version A, analysis code should check that data was produced using a version later than A"

Comment: so you want `git` to do your unit-testing for you?

Comment: I'm pretty much looking for an equivalent to "requires version 1.4.6 or higher", but I figured I'd ask the general form of the question, as it is likely to be useful to a wider audience.

Comment: `A and B share a child but not a parent` and `A and B share nothing` seem irrelevant since each git repository has only one root commit (the first commit, which doesn't have a parent). So, two commits in a repository have at least one parent in common : the root commit. But I may have misunderstood your need.

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont: Unless Linus: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/5126/ .  You can, in fact, merge two repositories, so as to have two roots.

Comment: You need not even merge two repositories, simply use `git checkout --orphan newbranch` to give yourself a branch that has no parents.

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont In addition to zebedia49's comment, it is entirely possible to have any arbitrary number of root commits in a single repository, and they don't even ever have to merge together. One could, for example have a completely separate history tree of commits for documentation versus the project source code. It's true that this is not very commonly done, but it's quite possible (and not even all that difficult).

Comment: WoW, I didn't knew about that. I'll have a look to it. Thanks !

Comment: Merging to repos and `checkout --orphan` are nice, but they are really used not so often. A real-life example of multiple roots is `git notes` and co. But you hardly ever try to find a common ancestor of a code and a note commit =).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checking for parent-child relation is easy, use [`git merge-base`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html). If the result is one of your commits, it's a parent, the other is a child.

I suggest ignoring the case when commits don't have a common ancestor. Sure, this can happen, but I'm not aware of any valid use-cases for this. I mean, you are solving a real problem for a real project, I'm sure you *can* assume that this won't happen. *BTW, `merge-base` will exit with an error, and it's the only situation when a merge-base doesn't exist, so you still can detect this case.*

Finding children for a commit is just impossible. Absoultely. You can't do that reliably. A commit has a “parent” reference, but it doesn't have “child” references. `rev-list --children` does a completely different thing, it has nothing to do with what you want. You’ll have to refine your problem.

What I can suggest instead is using `git branch --contains <commit>` or `git tag --contains <commit>` which will only list those branches/tags from which you can reach your commit.

Alternatively you can look at [`git for-each-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html) that will allow you to test if a commit is reachable from any of your branches/tags.

Comment: Finding children is by no means impossible. You just have to walk over all commits to be sure youve found them all.

Comment: @NevikRehnel you can't walk over all the commits. You just can't do that. You've got a bunch of “tips”, those are branches, tags, stash, etc. Of course you can walk them all, but that's a bit difficult, and still you haven't found all the commits. Suppose, I've just created a commit and immediately reset the branch to the previoud one. The commit is still there, I can refer to it by its hash, but there are no refernces to it in the repository (except for ref-log entries, of course).

Comment: @NevikRehnel This is just a question of definition of “children”, that's whay I mean by saying “the problem should be refined”. You seem to think that a child is a commit, reachable from one of the branch-references, who's parent is a commit in question. OK, that's fine, I addressed this in my question. For me a “child” is a commit, whose parent is the commit in question. There is simply no comprehensive list of commits in the git repo, you can't find them all.

Comment: naturally unreachable commits would not be included, but that's normal for any "real problem" as you like to put it. Also, git fsck can find dangling objects if you want to be really thorough. And also, walking them isnt very difficult, you just get all the refs in a repo and start walking down their ancestry

Comment: @NevikRehnel define what is a “reachable commit” if we are considering only “real problems”.